# Why aren't all NP-complete problems strongly NP-complete, if any NP problem can be reduced to an NP-complete problem

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, np-complete

So we know that :
(1). A problem is NP-complete if every other problem in NP can be reduced to it in polynomial time
(2). A problem is said to be strongly NP-complete if a strongly NP-complete problem has a polynomial reduction to it and it is in NP itself

But then this would seem to imply that every NP-complete problem A is strongly NP-complete, since let there be a strongly NP-complete problem B. Then, B is in NP, and so by (1), B can be reduced to A. But then by (2), A is strongly NP-complete.

Since weak NP-complete problems such as the knapsack problem exist, why isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_NP-complete

Comment: @GregMartin I don't think those are relevant here. It seems that OP's terminology is strange; their "strongly NP-complete" seems to mean "NP-complete" (in the standard sense) and their "NP-complete" seems to mean "NP-hard" (in the standard sense).